# windows subsystem install mysql server

Tags: mysql, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

installing mysql-server on ubuntu 18.04 subsystem windows 10.

```
Cannot open /proc/net/unix: No such file or directory
Cannot stat file /proc/1/fd/5: Operation not permitted
Cannot stat file /proc/3/fd/7: Operation not permitted
```

help please

[image]

Comment: "Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) is a compatibility layer that allows Linux ELF64 binaries to run natively on Windows 10"  Why not installing the native MySQL Windows 64bit version and install that?  MySQL is designed to work cross os well ok using uppercase where the database name/table name and or columns are lowercase might give trouble between OS and could made the same binary table files.

Comment: If I had to install MySQL for Linux on Windows 10, I'd setup a Linux Virtual Machine running under Oracle VirtualBox, or ...

Answer (score 7):

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 under Windows 10 as a Subsystem, so You have to start off by adding repositories required by MariaDB by :

> sudo apt-get install software-properties-common

Then update your installation by :

> sudo apt update

Install MariaDB by :

> sudo apt install mariadb-server

You’ll be prompted to set a root password and wait for the installation to continue. Issue the following command once installation is complete:

> sudo service mysql start

That’s it and to check both your mysql and mariadb version try:

> mysql --version

Comment: I'm not prompted at all for setting the root password

Comment: Do you connect by sudo and check that your terminal ask you for the root password?

Comment: I finally managed to solve my problem but sincerly that was so much try and errors that I can't figure out what solved it : / I think that XAMPP where conflicting too.

Comment: Good news that it works with you, actually we should be careful with the commands related to any database engine on Microsoft or any Linux distribution,  and trace errors when appears and not ignore to continue.

Answer (score 5):

[as mentioned a guy at github and it solved my problem](https://github.com/wslutilities/wslu/issues/101)
The problem is with the script "/etc/profile.d/wsl-integration.sh". As a quick workaround insert the following line before the first line in "/etc/profile.d/wsl-integration.sh" (use sudo to edit the file):

```
# Check if we have HOME folder
if [ "${HOME}" = "/" ]; then
  return
fi
```

I mean before the line:

```
WSL_INTEGRATION_CACHE=$HOME/.cache/wslu/integration`
```

Comment: hehe, it is strange to read "a guy" when they refer to me. There is an improved answer to this in the same link. I will edit here also

Comment: I don't have that file on my system

Comment: @CarlosRafaelRamirez lol... :D... *cough*.... a gentleman...

Answer (score 4):

For anyone running into this issue, Close and reopen WSL and then run 
sudo service mysql start
sudo dpkg --configure -a
it should complete.

Answer (score 3):

I had a MySQL already running on my native Windows 10 system. It must have been trying to fight for the same defaults. I tried switching native MySQL off and then working with WSL installation and it worked somehow.

Comment: That's it! I forgot I had XAMPP running on Windows. Once I stopped MySQL on Windows, the installation on WSL succeeded.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

I meet save issue. The reason is you have a MySQL-server installed on your native OS Win10. How to fix it:

1. Go to Windows service, stop the MySQL service.
2. Modify my.ini under MySQL server folder, mine is `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5`

   ```
   [mysqld]
   \# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on
   port=3306 -> 3308 or other
   ```
3. Restart your wsl instance.
4. Reinstall the MySQL-server with root account

   ```
   apt install mysql-server
   service mysql start
   mysql_secure_installation
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I can't install mysql on wsl either (mysql 5.7.30, ubuntu 18.04, win10 1909), so there is workaround here. Install and run mysql on windows, then connect it from ubuntu bash by using:

```
mysql -u root -p --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306 --protocol=TCP
```

Also need to config Database in your porject settings. Don't use localhost, and port is 3306 on my pc, might be different from yours. Hope they can fix it on wsl2.