# Cannot install mysql-server on WSL

Tags: mysql, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL and I am trying to install MySQL-server

I keep get the error as displayed on the screenshot attached..I have tried several times to

- apt remove --purge MySQL*
- apt-get autoremove
- apt-get autoclean
- sudo dpkg --configure -a
- sudo apt-get install -f
- sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Any ideas? I keep coming up with the same error.

[error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oATv7.png)

Comment: Please add all errors to the question in readable form. That console output is pure text, so there is no need to add an image

Comment: Additionally, have you tried running the hints from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54835516/windows-subsystem-install-mysql-server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [windows subsystem install mysql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54835516/windows-subsystem-install-mysql-server)

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem and I took these steps to fix it. **If you want the quick TL;DR, just jump to either the step 2 (for MySQL 5.x) or the step 4 (for MySQL 8.x).** I just include the other two steps as well to say more about what *didn't work for me*(but might be still helpful to someone else):

**STEP1:**

Some people get errors about *sockets*(just like pipes, sockets are things that make the communication between mysql server and its clients possible) and thus suggest using command line option `--protocl=TCP` or adding `--protocol:tcp` to the `mysqld.conf` to make it use TCP instead of these sockets(*which are better for faster local connection*). But there's the error `Error writing /etc/mysql/mysqld.conf.d/mysqld.conf: No such file or directory"` when I try to save that configuration file (initiated with "sudo nano").
I even cleaned up everything and installed mysql once again from scratch:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql
sudo apt-get remove --purge *mariadb*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

But still even that configuration file doesn't exist for me.

**STEP2:**

I see that running `mysql` says `mysql.exe: command not found`, so I think the main problem is with finding the executable from PATH. But the `/etc/bin/mysql` exists and also the `/etc/bin` is in the PATH, so I don't know why I get the *command-not-found* error when I run the `mysql`. Anyway, I run the `/etc/bin/mysql` and it gives yet another error:
`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`
Accidentally, I try `sudo mysql` and all of a sudden it successfully connects to the mysql server and shows the version 5.7. i.e., only adding the `sudo` made it work! I am not a Linux guru but I [used to] think that when `sudo` is needed, I should get a `permission error` and not a `mysql.exe: command not found`.

**STEP3:**

I'm following a tutorial which is based on MySQL 8. So I think *probably* upgrading to MySQL version 8 might fix both of my issues(it turns out that the necessity of `sudo` is not an *issue* at all, it *has to be there* normally, [if not configured otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37239970/connect-to-mysql-server-without-sudo)). So I follow the instructions in [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#repo-qg-apt-replacing). I add the MySQL APT repositories to my repository list, and then apt update & re-install the mysql-server. This time, I get a window which asks about the version and I choose version 8. Installation finishes and `sudo mysql --version` gives `mysql Ver 8.0.20 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)`, HOWEVER, this time even `sudo mysql` gives the error: `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`. Now even `sudo` is not helping!

**STEP4:**

I check the error log in `/var/log/mysql/error.log` and realize there's a problem with this description: `Linux Native AIO interface is not supported on this platform`. so I Google it and finally fix my issue with MySQL version 8 installation on WSL using [this very helpful comment from @jw-redpanda](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3631#issuecomment-465966498):

**Direct installation of MySQL 8.x will not work on WSL 1**(that's probably the reason why we failed at step 3). It has problem starting the server. Steps below should work:

**1. Remove MySQL 8.x:**

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client
sudo apt-get -y autoremove
```

**2. Change to MySQL 5.x candidate:**

`sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.15-1_all.deb`
(if you don't have it, get it from here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/)

**3. Double check current apt policy of MySQL is 5.x:**

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**4. Install MySQL 5.x**

```
sudo service mysql start (this should work without error)
```

**5. Change to MySQL 8.x candidate**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt policy mysql-server (it will show 8.x is the default candidate)
```

**6. Install MySQL 8.x**

`sudo apt-get -y install mysql-server`

**7. Modify a script as there is a bug**

```
sudo nano /etc/init.d/mysql
(search for a line ". /usr/share/mysql/mysql-helpers" and change it to
". /usr/share/mysql-8.0/mysql-helpers")
```

**8. Upgrade system tables to MySQL 8.x**

```
sudo service mysql start (this should start without error)
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

Hope this also works for you!

Answer (score 2):

As per your output, Its looks like package `mysql-server` depends on `mysql-server-5.7` but `mysql-server-5.7` was not configured properly in previous installation.So you can remove `mysql-server-5.7` and its packages and install again.

**Removing 'mysql-server-5.7` and its dependencies**

```sh
sudo dpkg -r mysql-client-5.7
sudo dpkg -r mysql-server-5.7
sudo dpkg -r libmysqlclient20:i386
sudo dpkg -r libmysqlclient20:amd64
sudo dpkg -r libmysqlclient18:amd64
sudo dpkg -r mysql-common
```

**Re-installing mysql-server**

```sh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mysql-server
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```