# My-Sql Server not installing in linux shell

Tags: mysql, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04

I tried installing MySql-server on Window Sub-system for Linux and this error kept resurfacing

```
 * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                         [ OK ]
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
Cannot open /proc/net/unix: No such file or directory
Cannot stat file /proc/1/fd/4: Operation not permitted
Cannot stat file /proc/1/fd/7: Operation not permitted
Cannot stat file /proc/4/fd/4: Operation not permitted
Cannot stat file /proc/919/fd/8: Operation not permitted
Cannot stat file /proc/919/fd/4: Operation not permitted
mysqld will log errors to /var/log/mysql/error.log
mysqld is running as pid 3044
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

And

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up software-properties-common (0.99.22.6) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                  Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.20-2ubuntu4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried forcing the installation using

```
 sudo apt-get install
```

and fixing the installation

```
sudo apt install --fix-broken
```

I tried configuring the dpkg and clearing the cache  the same error kept on surfacing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [windows subsystem install mysql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54835516/windows-subsystem-install-mysql-server)

Comment: Since MySQL works well in Windows and Linux, using WSL to run it will not be as performant as installing the native MySQL for Windows. If you run MySQL on Windows, you can still access all the databases from within WSL, you just need to specify the url to your PC.

Comment: I did that already and I followed the instructions in the link @Arthur. MySql isn't running

Comment: Sorry, did you install MySQL in Windows? Can you connect to it via Mysql WorkBench? Then from within WSL try to connect to it using port 127.0.0.1